# List only blobs/files in a container and not directories, sub-directories, sub-files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, blobstorage

Let's say that I have the following file structure in my azure storage account.

```
container-1
    directory-1
        file-1-1.csv
        file-1-2.json
        file-1-3.jpeg
    directory-2
        file-2-1.csv
    file-1.csv
    file-2.csv
container-2
    directory-1
        directory-1-1
            file1-1-1.csv
```

I want to list only files (file-1.csv, file-2.csv) inside container-1 and not any other results is there a way to make such a request.

Currently, the URL which I am using is this:

```
https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/container-1?comp=list&restype=container&prefix=/
```

which returns:

```
directory-1
directory-1/file-1-1.csv
directory-1/file-1-2.json
directory-1/file-1-3.jpeg
directory-2
directory-2/file-2-1.csv
file-1.csv
file-2.csv
```

while I only need:

```
file-1.csv
file-2.csv
```

Comment: You want to use the REST API to list the blobs or use some SDK for that purpose?

Comment: I want to use REST API to list blobs in a container. But I need results only for direct files and not the indirect ones stored in nested directories.

Comment: So you want REST API to return just the file names and nothing else. Correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, exactly that. Additionally, those files should be direct children of the path specified. As in the above example, you can see even file-2-1.csv being returned which is not a direct child of container-1

Comment: The Azure Blob storage is not that sophisticated and does not have a complex filtering capability. It does return a piece of XML which can be filtered eg with XPath or converted to a dataframe. Where are you calling this from? eg Azure Data Factory, Databricks Notebook, PowerShell, curl? This will impact the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to list just blobs using Blob Storage REST API. There is very limited server-side filtering support available there and listing just blobs is not one of them.

One "hacky" way would be to filter blobs by prefix. Assuming all files at the container level start with some pre-defined characters (`file` for example) and no virtual directories at that level start with those characters, then you can specify `file` as prefix and then REST API will only return the blobs names of which start with those characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `List Blobs` request to the Azure Blob REST API. In that request you can specify a delimiter in the querystring. Use the delimiter `/`.

That'll cause the result to list all your blobs that are in the root of your request to use the XML `<Blob>` element. All blobs that are not in the root of your search will appear grouped under a `<BlobPrefix>` element with the foldername. Discard all `<BlobPrefix>` elements and you're left with only the blobs that are not contained in (another) 'folder'.

Comment: I believe OP wants REST API to return only blobs and no virtual folders.

Comment: @GauravMantri true, but this is as close you can get to what OP wants. It significantly reduces the result set with requests containing multiple blobs in virtual folders. It is also a lot easier to filter elements on type than it is to filter on a character of the value inside a child element.

Comment: No disagreement there.